# Best procedure to implement observer design pattern in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns

This may be stupid question, but want to know the best ways and API's to implement observer design pattern in Android. 
 Say in my application I have classes which implements BLL , Models, UI and web service handling.  Now from one screen application hits web service and retrieves values which will be updating model class values. If bll classes wants the updated values, rather than checking for each value , bll would like to get notified for all updates. 
Different modules should be able to register and get notified for these kinds of event updates. 
What is the best solution to achieve the same.

Comment: That would depend a lot on what "modules" are and what the "specific event updates" are. I suggest that you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do in **significantly** more detail.

Comment: what do you mean by best, do you mean pull or push ?

Comment: @mmlooloo : I mean pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get notified for specific events, use the Observer interface in android, check it out in the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ...but want to know the best ways and API's to implement observer design pattern in Android.

As broad as it can be, the first thing that comes to mind is [ReactiveAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).